# Microsoft Access, auto generate columns in DataSheet subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I want to create a form in MS Access 2003 that lets the user pick from any existing query, and then have it display the results inside the form (as a sub-form in DataSheet view).  The user will then be able to select one or more records and click a button on the parent form to do certain actions based on the selection.  I want it to be able to work with any query, with very few limits, and display the full results of the query (all columns).  The only requirement I might have is that it include certain fields for certain actions.  For example, if I have a "send email" action, the query will require a field named "email", or maybe "to" and "subject".

Changing the DataSource of the DataSheet sub-form at run-time isn't a problem, I've done that before using VBA.  Getting the columns displayed to change is the problem.

In a .NET WinForms app this could be done with the "auto generate columns" on a GridView control, or using the GridView.Columns collection directly in code.  In VBA I don't see a way to add/remove columns from a DataSheet view.  I also don't see a way to auto generate them based on the query.  It appears the columns are controlled by the controls placed on the form (in form view), and while it is possible to add/remove controls using VBA, the form would have to be placed in Design  View and require exclusive access to the database -- sounds very messy and I would like to avoid the exclusive access part.

Am I missing something?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it. Create a blank subForm control on your main form. To change the source and the columns just leave the source object blank, then when you set it with code, the columns will reset to whatever source you use. So set it like so:

```
Private Sub setSource()
    Me.subForm.SourceObject = "Query.myQuery"
End Sub
```

Then to get the selected items, assuming you know what column you want, you would do something like this:

```
Private Sub getSelected()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim f As Form

    Set f = Me.subForm.Form
    Set rs = f.RecordsetClone

    Debug.Print f.SelTop
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst

    rs.Move f.SelTop - 1
    Debug.Print rs!ID
End Sub
```

If you don't know the column explicitly you can use this to loop through the columns of the selected item and run some analysis on each name until you determine it's the column you want.

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't think about that SourceObject, and that it can be a table, query, or even Recordset.

Comment: Brilliant! If you're looking for a way to get Pivot Query data (with dynamic # of columns) on a Form, this SourceObject setting with a subform object does it in seconds. Pivot functions for form design were removed in Access 2013, so all videos showing it are obsolete, and I did not find any documentation for this in relation to Pivot queries and tables on Microsoft's sites.